# remove delete item from listbox list of items

Tags: .net, winforms

I have listbox with collection of items. After deleting item from the listbox I want to remove that item from the listbox without reloading whole collection again, is this possible in winforms?

```
 private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MyData sel = (MyData)listBox1.SelectedItem;
            if (...delete data)
            {
                listBox1.Items.Remove(listBox1.SelectedItem);
                MessageBox.Show("succ. deleted!");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("error!");
            }           
        }
```

I'm getting error

> items collection cannot be modified when the datasource property is
>   set

Answer (score 1):

Hey Try to Get Selected item index from your collection then remove item form collection by index then again bind your list box to collection..

I have made sample code please refer.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    List<String> lstProduct = new List<String>();
    public Form1()
    {

        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public List<String> BindList()
    {

        lstProduct.Add("Name");
        lstProduct.Add("Name1");
        lstProduct.Add("Name2");
        lstProduct.Add("Nam3");
        lstProduct.Add("Name4");

        return lstProduct;
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listBox1.DataSource = BindList();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // The Remove button was clicked.
        int selectedIndex = listBox1.SelectedIndex;

        try
        {
            // Remove the item in the List.
            lstProduct.RemoveAt(selectedIndex);
        }
        catch
        {
        }

        listBox1.DataSource = null;
        listBox1.DataSource = lstProduct;
    }
}
```

Hope it helps you....

Comment: Need to use an ObservableCollection to notify the UI of the deletion

Comment: @Blam as per my knowledge ObservableCollection is used in WPF Application not Traditional Win form.

Comment: Thanks for this post, tried but I'm experience performance issues when loading whole list again.

Answer (score 0):

You should use an observable collection as a `DataSource`.
You can use built-in ones, such as [`BindingList<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132679.aspx) and [`ObservableCollection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx).

But you may also consider creating your own collection and implement either [`IBindingList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.ibindinglist.aspx) or [`INotifyCollectionChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.inotifycollectionchanged.aspx) interface.

**Update**

```
public partial class YourForm : Form
{
    private BindingList<string> m_bindingList = new BindingList<string>();

    private YourForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        yourListBox.DataSource = m_bindingList;

        // Now you can add/remove items to/from m_bindingList
        // and these changes will be reflected in yourListBox.

        // But you shouldn't (and can't) modify yourListBox.Items
        // as long as DataSource is set.
    }

    private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Removing items by indices is preferable because this avoids
        // having to lookup the item by its value.
        m_bindingList.RemoveAt(yourListBox.SelectedIndex);
    }
}
```

Comment: can you elaborate more with concrete hints on this example. I tried with @Nerraj Dubey answer example but performance is really bad.